# UWP efcore issue when adding new entity containing another existing entity

Tags: entity-framework, uwp

I have an issue with efcore in UWP. I would like to use one DbContext per request because it seems it is the best way to use efcore. But my issue occurs when I try to add new entity containing an existing entity. For example:
I have a Blog that contains a post list. So, the post contains an instance of Blog.
Suppose I added a blog. After that when I try to add a new Post with added blog as Blog, I have an SQLiteException:

> SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Blogs.BlogId'

So what is the best way to prevent this issue?

I posted a sample project on github [here](https://github.com/SamuelLioult/net-issues/tree/master/efcore/EfCoreTester)

In this sample, add a blog and then add a post and the error should occur.

Here a minimal part of the code:

Blog model:

```
class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}
```

Post model:

```
class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext:

```
class EfCoreTesterContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=efcoretester.sqlite");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Blog)
            .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogId);
    }
}
```

The data access methods:

```
class DataAccessService
{
    #region Singleton

    public static DataAccessService Instance { get; } = new DataAccessService();

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    private DataAccessService()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public void AddBlog(Blog blog)
    {
        using (var db = new EfCoreTesterContext())
        {
            db.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<Blog> GetBlogs()
    {
        using (var db = new EfCoreTesterContext())
        {
            return db.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void AddPost(Post post)
    {
        using (var db = new EfCoreTesterContext())
        {
            db.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<Post> GetPosts()
    {
        using (var db = new EfCoreTesterContext())
        {
            return db.Posts.ToList();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find it hard to find someone who will download your whole project. May I suggest that you add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your followed up questions, as currently we have three tables,`Person`,`Blog`  and `Post`. Both `Person` to `Post` and `Blog` to `Post` are one to many relationships. How to add records?

In that case, the `Post` should contains two foreign keys. So caused by the foreign keys constraint, whenever you have one  new `Post` record you should assign the referenced `Blog` as well as the `Person`.

To simply that, you can think about this, add `Blog` records, then add `Person` records, now we can dependently add new posts with the existing `BlogId` and the `PersonId` as the foreign keys.

> In this case is it necessary to add my new post in the Blog.Posts list AND in the Owner.Posts list too?

So for this issue, when you add new posts with `Blog`, at same time you must assign a existed `Person`. And you cannot add `Blog` with posts without an exist `Person`,vice verse. You don't need to add the posts list again to the referenced `Person` since you have already force to assign them to posts.

Answer (score 3):

> UWP efcore issue when adding new entity containing another existing entity

According to your code snippet, the model shows a one-to-many relationship between `Blog` and `Post`. `Post` is the dependent entity,`Blog` is the principal entity.

Since the `Post.BlogId` is the foreign key, when you want to add `Post` instance with an existing `Blog`, you should add the existing `Blog.BlogId` to the foreign key column to have the a foreign key constraint. So for adding new `Post` with existing `Blog` you should update the adding new `Post` section as follows:

```
private async void btnAddPost_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPostMessage.Text))
    {
        Blog exsitblog = lvBlogs.SelectedItem as Blog;
        var newPost = new Post() { Message = txtPostMessage.Text, BlogId = exsitblog.BlogId }; 
        //var newPost = new Post() { Message = txtPostMessage.Text, Blog = lvBlogs.SelectedItem as Blog };
        DataAccessService.Instance.AddPost(newPost);
        txtPostMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        lvPosts.Items.Add(newPost);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Please enter post name");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Your original code line is for creating a new `Post` entity with a new `Blog` entity referenced, so that the exception thrown since you add an same record to the `Blog` table. For adding new `Post` with new `Blog` referenced should as follows:

```
private async void btnAddPost_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPostMessage.Text))
    { 
        Blog withnewblog = new Blog()
        {
            BlogId = 5,
            Name = "test"
        };
        var newPost = new Post() { Message = txtPostMessage.Text, Blog = withnewblog }; 
        DataAccessService.Instance.AddPost(newPost);
        txtPostMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        lvPosts.Items.Add(newPost);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Please enter post name");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will implement this way on my github project and on my professional project.

Comment: It seems there is another issue using this way. Suppose my Post entity has also a Owner (existing) entity. In this case there is also a one-to-many relation. In this case is it necessary to add my new post in the Blog.Posts list AND in the Owner.Posts list too?

Comment: @Samuel LIOULT, you cannot add a Post without Blog information,or the BlogId, or the Blog entity. How you suppose the Post entity already have one without reference to a Blog? One to many in your scenario is One(Blog) to many(Post).You can add one Blog with a new Post list.  Did you require a many to many relationship?

Comment: I think you don't understand my last message. So, imagine I have a new entity type named Person which is the owner of the post. I still have Blog which is principal entity with a list of Post (dependent entity). But now I have also a Person (principal entity) with a list of Post (dependent entity). So if I have an existing Blog and an existing Person, how can I add a new post attached to its blog and person?

Comment: @Samuel LIOULT, I add another answer to explain your follow up question, since comment is limited. If you still have new issues, I recommend to open a new thread, thanks for understanding.